# Finding all algebraic solutions to $x^2+y^2=a^2$, for $a$ real, with "no radicals, fractional powers, or trigonometric functions"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $a\in\mathbb R$. Construct the all possible algebraic solution sets of the equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$, over $\mathbb R$, under the following condition:
>
> - $x$ and $y$ contain no radicals, fractional powers, or trigonometric functions.

I realized that

$$x=a\sin \alpha, y=a\cos\alpha$$
and $$y=\pm\sqrt {a^2-x^2}\\ x=\pm\sqrt {a^2-y^2}$$ can not be considered as a solution.

So, I'm thinking, thinking, thinking... To make an attempt, I need to have at least an idea. I can't find a way to escape using the radical. Seems almost impossible.

Comment: See the "alternative parametrization" in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations)

Comment: Any right triangle with legs x, y and  hypotenuse a?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Isn't "t" a  disguised trigonometric function?

Comment: @user It's not a disguised function at all, just a parameter.  Of course you could express it as a trigonometric function of a different parameter $\theta$, but so what?

Comment: @RobertIsrael It's well disguised then! :)

Comment: Without loss of generality you can consider $a=1$. Then the general solution simply would be found by scaling by $a$. For $x^2+y^2=1$ there is the rational parametrization of the unit circle.

Comment: $$\left(\frac{2at}{t^2+1},\frac{a(t^2-1)}{t^2+1}\right)$$

Comment: If $t=\tan\theta,$ $\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=\sin2\theta,$ and  $\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\cos2\theta.$

Comment: @user Hello..I guess I obtained these formulas without trigo

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the method where I get the results you want when I apply it.

Let $$x^2+y^2=a^2$$ and let $m\neq 0$. Then, you can write:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&y^2=(a-x)(a+x)\\
\implies &\begin{cases} a-x=\frac ym, m\neq 0\\ a+x=my\end{cases}\\
\implies &\begin{cases}2a=y\left(m+\frac 1m\right)\\
 2x=y\left(m-\frac 1m\right)\end{cases}\\
\implies &y=\frac {2am}{m^2+1}\wedge x=\frac {a(m^2-1)}{m^2+1}.\end{aligned}
$$

Finally, we can observe that:

$$
\begin{aligned}x^2+y^2=\left(\frac {2am}{m^2+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac {a(m^2-1)}{m^2+1}\right)^2=a^2\end{aligned}
$$

holds $\forall m\in \mathbb R$.

Obviously, the formulas also work when $m=0$, thus we don't need the restriction $m\neq 0$.